# Один onClickListener для большого количества кнопок (Android)

Tags: android, java

Доброй ночи! У меня в программе имеется больше, чем 30 кнопок, для которых ставится `onClickListener` в одном классе, то есть:

```
`button.setOnClickListener(mylistener);`
```

и немного ниже:

```
public OnClickListener mylistener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_mm:

    инструкции
    break;

    И так далее
    }

  }
 }
```

В чём суть вопроса: этот метод `OnClickListener` необходимо перенести в отдельный класс. Как это сделать? Как потом к нему "приписать" кнопку?
Извиняюсь за ошибки в тексте, так как пишу с планшета.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишу из того, что понял

```
   public class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            //творю, что хочу
        }
    }

button.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());
```

Comment: @Andreich, всё сработало, спасибо. Но как из этого класса выполнить метод в Main.class?

Comment: не понял совсем вопрос. Если вы хотите, чтобы Main.class можно было посылать как слушателя  в button.setOnClickListener(), то вам надо сделать так, чтобы Main.class реализовывал интерфейс View.OnClickListener

Comment: я понял вопрос ) Нужно передать этот самый main в качестве параметра в конструкторе customclicklistenera. Потом в активити создаёте customCliclListener listener = new customOnClickListener(this), а в самом листенере для вызова методов пользуетесь конструкцией main.method(); Но это всё извращение - если можно перенести метод в клас листенера, то лучше сделать это

Answer (score 3):

Любой виджет(контрол) в Android унаследован от базового класса [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). В свою очередь каждому `View` можно поставить в соответсвтвие некоторый идентификатор (далее `ID`).

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/my_button"
....
/>
```

`ID` обычно назначаются в xml и используются для нахождения контрола в текущем дереве всех View.

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Детектирование нажатия(`click`) на любой `View` (не обязательно `Button`) происходит по средством реализации интерфейса [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). Это можно сделать двумя способами: имплеменировав этот интерфейс `Activity` либо создать инстанс анонимного класса (`new View.OnClickListener()`). Но главное что надо сделать - это в обязательном порядке переопределить метод `OnClick()` интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`. Да, и не забыть, что надо назначить необходимому контрлу его слушателя (`view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)`). В добавок один слушатель можно назначить для любого количества контролов.

Как различать по какому `View` было совершено нажатие? Достаточтно только посмотреть на сигнатуру метода `onClick` интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public abstract void onClick (View v){}
```

Внутри этого метода разработчики позволяют нам использовать ссылку на `View`, по которому было совершено нажатие (в данном случае это `View v`). Осталось просто отличать различные view по их индивидуальному признаку. Тут нам на помощь приходит идентификатор `ID`. Метод [view.getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) возвращает нам значении идентификатора коткретного контрола. Осталось только сопоставить его.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.my_button1:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break; // вызывается для выхода из блока switch (при вызове дальнейший код не исполняется)
                case R.id.my_button2:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
                case R.id.my_button3:
                     //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
                case R.id.my_button4:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
            }
        }
```

ps. Стоит обратить внимание, что для системы ID является значением типа int.

pps. Есть еще 1 способ детектирования нажатия, посредством прямого вызова метода:

```
        <Button
        android:onClick="method"
        ...
        />
```

В этом случае просто вызывается указаный метод. Более подробно про этот вариант почитать тут

Comment: прекрасный ответ на другой вопрос. спрашивали не том...